# How Install Media9?

Tags: media9

I just downloaded the media9.zip package and unzipped it to a subdirectory of C:\texlive. But I don't know where to go from here.

The documentation says:
"MiKTeX and TeXLive users should run the package manager for installation", but I don't see anything in the folder tree with names resembling 'package manager' or 'installation'.

Comment: The package manager belongs to the TeX installation, not to a particular LaTeX package. The Package manager of TeXLive is called  **tlmgr**. In Windows it can be found somewhere in the Start menu, I guess. You don't need to download and install the file `media9.zip` manually.

Comment: 1. The answer by @AlexG enabled me to load media9 (at least the errors I'm now getting don't complain of its absence), but I don't see how to vote it as best.\\2. Please confirm what I was told: that it's bad etiquette on this site to say 'thank you' (otherwise I would say that).  \\3. Neither double slashes nor carriage return seems to work for causing a new line in these comments. How do I do that?

Comment: (1) It is only a comment, you cannot upvote it nor mark it as the best answer. (2) It is like that, indeed. (3) There is no way for carriage return in comments.

Comment: @PeytonTodd On a side note, if you're using ``\\`` in your TeX code (except in tables), you're almost certainly doing it wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `\usepackage{media9}` inside your TeX-File. It should ask you and download it automatically. If this isn't the case use the Windows Search to find your TeXLive Package Manager

It should look like this:
[image]

Get in the `Name`-Field, insert "media9" and press Enter. After that you should find the `media9`-package. If it's not installed, right click on it and press on `Install`

Comment: I guess, it  is TeXLive what the OP installed, not MiKTeX.

Comment: So you are telling me that I'm giving out wrong information even tho [you tell him the very same](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250199/how-install-media9/250200?noredirect=1#comment596284_250199)? Don't you think you should read my answer first, before you judge it?

Comment: I read your answer even trice. Your screenshot shows the MiKTeX-Package manger, not the one of TeXLive. This might confuse the OP.

Comment: You gave detailed instructions on how to install a package in MiKTeX. But the OP is trying to make his first steps with LaTeX using the TeXLive distribution, which is not MiKTeX. TeXLive doesn't have on-the-fly package installation, nor does its package manager look like the screenshot. Just reword your answer to make clear it is referring to MiKTeX. We can delete the comments then.

Comment: ok, thats information i can use. Welp, i thought that both use the same or similar package manager